# How to resolve java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: java, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
APP_NO,BUS_APP_DATA_OWNER_CDSID_C,DEV_APP_SUPVSR_CDSID_C,BUS_SUB_ORG_NO,
STATUS_NO,APP_NAME,APP_ACRONYM,APP_DESC,ITMSA14_ID_R,APP_BUSEXEC_SPNSR,
APP_BUSPROG_MGR,APP_APPGRP_MGR,APP_PRAC_SUPVSR,APP_IT_OWNER,
TMSA77_ITMS_TYPE_K,IT_SUB_ORG_NO,AP.APP_FAMILY_NO,SLA.TMSA77_LOOKUP_K 
     FROM APPLICATION AP 
LEFT JOIN APP_FAMILY AF 
       ON AP.APP_FAMILY_NO=AF.APP_FAMILY_NO 
LEFT JOIN ITMSA77_LOOKUP SLA 
       ON SLA.TMSA77_LOOKUP_K = AP.TMS77_APP_SLA_K 
      AND TMSA77_LOOKUP_TYPE_C = 'SLA'
    WHERE IT_ORG_NO = 27 
    ORDER BY APP_NO
```

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00913: too many values

I get this error only in run time. But when i try to run this query in sql developer tool, it works perfectly.

Please suggest, how can i modify this query to get rid of that error.

Comment: That's a big old wall of SQL. If you want somebody to read it, can I suggest you try to format it (indent by 4 spaces, and insert line breaks/indentation to make it readable).

Comment: might be used with a cursor, perhaps you're using with into clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that your SELECT is part of an INSERT and your number of insert columns isn't the same number of the select columns.

Comment: Yes, there is an Insert statement based on the results fectching from this query. we figured out that the problem is in Insert statement , not in this query. Thanks for looking into this and sharing your comments. The issue is resolved now.